# How To Fix Leak Under Sink (Pic)

Tags: plumbing, leak, kitchen-sink

This pipe under my sink just recently started leaking at a very slow drip. The knob doesn't budge either way, at least not with my hand.

[image]

[image]

Best way to address it? I was thinking I could simply get some plumbers tape and maybe a cap to just close it up? Or is that not good practice?

If a cap would work, can anyone eyeball what size that it is so I can find it online or ask for it at the store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rubber/neoprene washer on the end of the valve stem needs to be replaced, a very simple cheap fix. If you choose to go the route of a cap for the spout will work too. Search online for a brass 3/4" threaded hose cap